# How to handle if XPath are different for multiple sub-menu options

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have situation when i have click main menu options it will be display 10 different sub-menu options. In all sub-menu section is available 2nd sub-menu options which is available more than 20 menu options and all are dynamic.

```
<a id="ui-id-11" class="ui-corner-all" href="https://www.xyz.com/abc" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
<span>Helmets</span>
</a>
```

This above sub-menu - my xpath is - `//*[@id='ui-id-11']/span`

```
<a id="ui-id-12" class="ui-corner-all" href="https://www.abc.com/abc" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
<span>Riding Gear</span>
</a>
```

This above sub-menu's if- my xpath is - `//*[@id='ui-id-12']/span`

How to handle all the sub-menu options to the single Xpath?

Comment: you cannot have a single xpath for multiple sub-menu.what are you exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to locate a specific sub-menu item which may not have the same ID each time you access it? If so, this is a duplicate as @BharatMane suggests

Comment: yup..as per his details given in the question may he wants to locate a specific sub-menu item which may not have the same ID's every time. So, I think above question helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [X-Path predicate starts-with](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with) as follows -

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'ui-id-')]/span
```

**Update :**
But certainly this would not help your cause - You may need to use another predicate like [contains](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) to check whether particular text is present or not.

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'ui-id-')]/span[contains(text(),'Helmets')]
```

But in that case, whatever I suggested earlier in the answer is not useful. Better way is to create XPath dynamically -

```
String dropDwonOption = //assign value here dynamically like Helmet, Riding Gear
String xpath = "/span[contains(text(),'"+dropDwonOption+"')]";
```

And then use this xpath.

Comment: All right but, using this XPath it will finds all the sub-menus who have the same id's starting from  'ui-id-11',  'ui-id-12', 'ui-id-13' in this case what?